# Both sides of relationship must have the same no of columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-relationship

I'm trying to create relationship between two tables. The first has four columns First(idP, state, phone, no) and the second has 4 columns also: Second(id, fname, lname, city). However, when I try to make a relationship between them I get the error "Both sides of relationship must have the same number of columns". Well, they both have 4 columns.

Comment: How do you "try to make a relationship"? In the database? In Entity Framework? In which version of Entity Framework? In the designer? With Code-First, Fluent API, Annotations? Is your question about Entity Framework at all? In the current state your question is really unanswerable.

Comment: I'm making relationship according to this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

Comment: Perhaps the exception complains about a different number of foreign key columns and primary key columns you have selected, not about the total number of columns in the tables.

Comment: @Slauma +1 for spotting this first. This [Table Relationship Tutorial](http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_Create_foreign_key_contraints.php) may be a good refresh on foreign key basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-read the yellow note box on the bottom of the [link you provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx).  The error you are getting refers to the key only.  The key's have to be made up of the same number of columns.  The total number of columns in the tables need not match.

Also just an observation.  The two tables you have provided don't appear to have a matching column that would be a good candidate to create a key.  The primary key of one should have a matching field (foreign key) in the other.  Unless, your second table has no primary key of it's own.  Is the id field of table 2 a foreign key only??

Comment: The primary key in First is idP. The primary key in Second is id. I want id to be the foreign key when I make a relationship.

Comment: That would only work in a one-to-one relationship.  If it's a one to many you'll need to add another field to table 2 to hold the foreign key.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I tried creating the FK relationship with the Management Studio, I wasn't selecting columns in both tables because the comboboxes weren't obvious until you clicked inside the left table. It should have made no sense but I'm a beginner. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

A relationship between Tables stands from a matching-pointer of one or more columns where they match values in both tables, like if you have a record containing the same "Name" and "Address" then we know that it's referring to the same person.

It does not matter how many columns those Tables do actually have and whether they match or not, but when you set up the Relationship-Keys columns, you must have the same amount of columns for both of them.

See this image for column relationship-keys:

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- I suppose my monke brain needed pictures 'cause I skimmed too fast through Microsoft's documentation, which indeed tells you how to do this in step 7: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15#using-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 0):

If your PK table has only on PK, and the table with which you want to make a relation has composite a key, so at the time of creating a foreign key relation you need to remove the other keys that will show up as they are the part of composite key, so just keep the one you need as FK.
So after removal you will only have one Pk and one FK to connect.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution/Alternative Solution: ***Try to change the naming of the keys***

This occurs when the name of both the primary key and the Foreign key is similar. For example, mine was as shown below:

| Primary key | Foreign key |
| --- | --- |
| personId | personId |

I changed it to slightly so that they can have the same meaning but different format as shown below:

| Primary key | Foreign key |
| --- | --- |
| personID | person_Id |

It can either be something like:

- personID → personId
- personID → person_Id
- PersonId → personId
  *e.t.c.*...

Comment: Remember to check if there was an initial relationship created

Comment: That is between the **primary key** and itself as seen in the database diagram